# Why does WebClient.DownloadData sometimes reduce the resolution of images?

Tags: c#, image, networking, bitmapimage

I am trying to dynamically download favicons from websites for an application I am currently working on and wrote a bit of code to extract possible candidates from a given website. This all works fine but for some reason there is a big loss of quality after downloading using `WebClient.DownloadData` for some image files while others download just as expected. 
For example downloading [Microsoft's 128 x 128 px favicon](https://c.s-microsoft.com/favicon.ico?v2) results in a 16 x 16 px Bitmap using the following code:

```
public static string Temp()
    {
        string iconLink = "https://c.s-microsoft.com/favicon.ico?v2"; // <-- 128 x 128 PX FAVICON
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
        SecurityProtocolType[] protocolTypes = new SecurityProtocolType[] { SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3, SecurityProtocolType.Tls, SecurityProtocolType.Tls11, SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 };
        string base64Image = string.Empty;
        bool successful = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < protocolTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = protocolTypes[i];
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(iconLink)))
                {
                    Bitmap bmpIcon = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream, true, true));
                    if (bmpIcon.Width < 48 || bmpIcon.Height < 48) // <-- THIS CHECK FAILS, DEBUGGER SAYS 16 x 16 PX!
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    bmpIcon = (Bitmap)bmpIcon.GetThumbnailImage(350, 350, null, new IntPtr());
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bmpIcon.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                        base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                }
                successful = true;
                break;
            }
            catch { }
        }
        if (!successful)
        {
            throw new Exception("No Icon found");
        }
        return base64Image;
    }
```

As I stated earlier there are other domains where this down scaling occurs too and then again some where it doesn't.
So I was wondering:

1. Am I missing anything obvious as this just seems weird?
2. Why does this happen (and why do other image files like [protonmail's 48x48 px favicon](https://protonmail.com/favicon.ico)) download just fine without any loss?
3. Is there a way to change my code to possibly prevent such behavior?

Comment: WebClient has no code that changes the resolution of anything, it will return what was provided by the server. If the downloaded data is indeed a 128x128 icon file (with multiple various resolutions inside), my guess would be the Bitmap class not fully understanding the format.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen Thanks mate! That's exactly what happened. Image.FromStream() doesn't seem to automatically choose the best quality available when dealing with .ico files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out `Image.FromStream()` doesn't automatically choose the best quality available when dealing with .ico files.

Therefore changing

```
Bitmap bmpIcon = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream, true, true));
```

to

```
System.Drawing.Icon originalIcon = new System.Drawing.Icon(stream);
System.Drawing.Icon icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(originalIcon, new Size(1024, 1024));
Bitmap bmpIcon = icon.ToBitmap();
```

did the trick.

By creating a new icon with a very large size it takes the best quality available to then be converted to a bitmap.